# Pass an array within a query string?

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I am using Visual Composer in a Wordpress site.
Visual Composer have function called "Post Grid", which allows to show posts in grid based on different values.

I have created 3 custom post types called `shoes`, `cloth` and `jackets`.

I have created 1 post in each post type and put these 3 post in category called `Brand`. This category have ID = 9.

In Visual Composer plugin there is option to get data from "Custom Query".

[image]

What i trying to accomplish is to show all posts from same brand in this "Post Grid".

So far i only got this input field to work with a query string like this:

```
post_type=shoes?cat=9
```

This return correct post from this post type with the correct brand category, but i want it to return all posts from this category, regardless of post type.

I have also tried to pass an array like this:

```
post_type[]=shoes&post_type[]=cloth&post_type[]=jackets&cat=9
```

but this does not work. It return this output:

```
=shoes&post_type[]=cloth&post_type[]=jackets&cat=9″]
```

Looks like square brackets exit the shortcode used by Visual Composer.

WPBakery (author of Visual Composer) just told me the following:

*"Post Grid element allows using Custom query which are written in a WordPress native way – by using it you can build any query you like..."*

Any suggestion on how to pass array in querystring without having VC break code because of shortcode?

Comment: do you remember how you solve it?, having similar need now.